How to decode the Payload dictionaryRepresentation provided by MXDiagnosticPayload
I'm working with Metric Kit to identify the crashes in an iOS application. I'm getting the crash logs from MXDiagnosticPayload. But it's hard to determine the exact cause from the crash logs.
I have added the crash log got from the Metrics Kit Payload in below EX.
Is there any way to decode this Payload information.
EX :
{
    callStackTree =     {
        callStackPerThread = 1;
        callStacks =         (
                        {
                callStackRootFrames =                 (
                                        {
                        address = 6870587896;
                        binaryName = "libswiftCore.dylib";
                        binaryUUID = "EA723E3D-1906-3DAC-A7E9-E108052DFCAA";
                        offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 236024;
                        sampleCount = 1;
                        subFrames =                         (
                                                        {
                                address = 4380344756;
                                binaryName = MetricFW;
                                binaryUUID = "D401CEC6-56EE-3D87-9F0B-C8F203068BC3";
                                offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 16820;
                                sampleCount = 1;
                                subFrames =                                 (
                                                                        {
                                        address = 4374905208;
                                        binaryName = MetricKitSample;
                                        binaryUUID = "851BAC69-5619-3D08-AE36-41E65CA43E0E";
                                        offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 16760;
                                        sampleCount = 1;
                                        subFrames =                                         (
                                                                                        {
                                                address = 4374905300;
                                                binaryName = MetricKitSample;
                                                binaryUUID = "851BAC69-5619-3D08-AE36-41E65CA43E0E";
                                                offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 16852;
                                                sampleCount = 1;
                                                subFrames =                                                 (
                                                                                                        {
                                                        address = 6945439608;
                                                        binaryName = UIKitCore;
                                                        binaryUUID = "7BF01CFC-23F1-326A-AFD8-AD967FFECE28";
                                                        offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 14884728;
                                                        sampleCount = 1;
                                                        subFrames =                                                         (
                                                                                                                        {
                                                                address = 6938707608;
                                                                binaryName = UIKitCore;
                                                                binaryUUID = "7BF01CFC-23F1-326A-AFD8-AD967FFECE28";
                                                                offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 8152728;
                                                                sampleCount = 1;
                                                                subFrames =                                                                 (
                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                        address = 6938708496;
                                                                        binaryName = UIKitCore;
                                                                        binaryUUID = "7BF01CFC-23F1-326A-AFD8-AD967FFECE28";
                                                                        offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 8153616;
                                                                        sampleCount = 1;

I have successfuly identified the crash using the offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment value. But it's hard to verify each and every  offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment value to find the crash we are looking for.

It's the OpenStep format. PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.openStep should be a good solution.
